# I keep getting an error, "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897088/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

I'm trying to get to grips with programming, and have just started learning `C#`, so first off, apologies for probably asking a really basic question which may have been answered hundreds of times. However, I can't seem to understand the answers and relate the answers out there to what I am trying to do.

I keep getting "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'FirstConsoleApplication.Program.function(string)'"

Can anyone point out where I'm losing this? I'm using visual studio 2008.

```
namespace FirstConsoleApplication
{
   class Program
   {   
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Type in an integer vale");
          string num;
          num = Console.ReadLine();
          string result1 = function1(num);
          Console.WriteLine(result1);
          Console.ReadLine();
       }

       string function1(string x)
       {
          Int32 isnumber = 0;
          bool canConvert = Int32.TryParse(x, out isnumber);
          string returnValue;
          if (canConvert == true)
          {
             int val3 = Int32.Parse(x);

             switch (val3)
             {
                case 50:
                    returnValue = "yep its 50";
                    break;
                case 51:
                    returnValue = "hmmm.... its 51... what are you gonna do about that??";
                    break;
                case 52:
                    returnValue = "lets not get sloppy now...";
                    break;
                default:
                    returnValue = "nope, its definately something else";
                    break;
            };

        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = "Thats not a number";
        };
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you see off to the right, where it says "Related"?  And there are a bunch of people with the same question who already got answers that could help?  Shame on anyone adding answers to this question.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Type in an integer vale");` should be, `Console.WriteLine("Type in an integer value");`... just sayin'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete code

```
namespace FirstConsoleApplication
{
class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Type in an integer vale");
            string num;
            num = Console.ReadLine();
            string result1 = function1(num);
            Console.WriteLine(result1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string function1(string x)
        {
            Int32 isnumber = 0;
            bool canConvert = Int32.TryParse(x, out isnumber);
            string returnValue;
            if (canConvert == true)
            {
                int val3 = Int32.Parse(x);

                switch (val3)
                {
                    case 50:
                        returnValue = "yep its 50";
                        break;
                    case 51:
                        returnValue = "hmmm.... its 51... what are you gonna do about that??";
                        break;
                    case 52:
                        returnValue = "lets not get sloppy now...";
                        break;
                    default:
                        returnValue = "nope, its definately something else";
                        break;
                };

            }
            else
            {
                returnValue = "Thats not a number";
            };
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably leave this as an edit in your previous answer.

Comment: Sure but guy said that he's beginner so I gave him multiple solutions

Comment: Thanks! wow, wasn't expecting answers this quick! I haven't quick got my head around the use of 'static' so I think I'll need to read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function as static:

```
static string function1(string x)
{
    ...
}
```

When you create a class like `Program` in your example, you can only call non-static methods if you first declare an instance of that class. Static methods do not require an instance of your `Program` class. In your example you don't have any properties or class variables to worry about, so it makes sense to declare your function as static.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put static keyword in front of function1 like

```
static string function1(string x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Main() function is static (one per class) while your function1() function is not (one per instance). Adding "static" before "string function1(string x)" should fix this for you.